# Calling a batch file through a web page

Tags: batch-file, web

I would like to call a batch file via a web page.  Can you suggest to me the most appropriate way of doing this? Should I use Javascript or PHP?

Note: The command should be placed on a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [php exec function](http://php.net/function.exec)

Use the function to execute the command that you need.

Comment: This is right, but: Avoid to pass the name of the Script as a parameter to the php script, as this would create a security hole! (As the OP was asking about JavaScript or PHP)

Comment: @RolandBär according to the PHP: exec function, the script is taken as parameter. How can I pass it in another way?

Comment: @Sameer I don't know your specific use case, but if possible I would only pass the kind of function as a parameter to the php script. In the php script you can then call the batch script depending of the asked function. In this way your are only allowing some specific scripts to be executed from your web application.

Comment: I have used the following code for my php page.
[code]
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo exec('whoiam.bat');
echo "Done!";
} else {
// display the form
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="DO IT!">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
[/code]
Apparently the bat has not been executed, no log has been generated.
the bat file is a simple log generator.
the bat file is located on the same folder as the php pages on the server.